# How to list the stored procedures that contains more than seven join operations in SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server

I have a database that contains more than a thousand stored procedures. I need to list the stored procedures that contain more than seven join operations for optimization purpose.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you just start with the procs that run slow?

Answer (score 6):

Just examine ROUTINE_DEFINITION field in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES table

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
where (LEN(ROUTINE_DEFINITION) - 
       LEN(REPLACE(ROUTINE_DEFINITION, 'JOIN', ''))) / LEN('JOIN')>=7
```

Comment: This is not a knock on valex's answer, because I think it is the best approach you'll find short of writing something to parse the statement.  The routine definition is the literal text of the stored proc.  So if you have a comment with the word "JOIN" that counts.  If you have a table name that contains that, like "AdJOINingWidgets" that counts, too.  Still, for a quick hit to identify potentially troublesome procs this will probably do.

Answer (score 2):

The ROUTETINE_DEFINITION contains a maximum of 4000 characters. If you have large stored procedures it might not find all the joins.

The object_definition can contains more than 10000 characters, try the following code:

```
SELECT 
    name
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE 
    ((len(object_definition(object_id)) - len(replace(object_definition(object_id)  , 'JOIN', ''))) / 4) >= 7
```